# How does Java handle arguments separated by |?

Tags: java, methods, arguments

How does Java handle arguments separated by | ?

for example

```
private void foo(int i) {
    System.out.println(i);
}

private void bar() {
    foo(1 | 2 | 1);
}
```

Which would give the output

```
3
```

I've seen this used in SWT/JFace widget constructors. What I can't figure out is how the value of `i` is decided.

Comment: You know that | is not a separator, it's the bitwise OR operator

Comment: I've actually never run into bitwise operators in Java, that's probably why I didn't realize it, it makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `|` is a bitwise or-operator.

```
foo(1 | 2 | 1);
```

means *call foo with the argument 1 bitwise-or 2 bitwise-or 1*.

- `1` in binary is `01`
- `2` in binary is `10`

Bitwise or of `01` and `10` is `11` which is 3 in decimal.

Note that the `|` operator can be used for booleans as well. Difference from the `||` operator being that the second operand is evaluated even if the first operand evaluates to `true`.

Actually, *all* bitwise operators work on booleans as well, including the xor `^`. Here however, there are no corresponding logical operator. (It would be redundant, since there is no way of doing a "lazy" evaluation of `^` :)

Comment: +1 for "second operand is evaluated even if the first operand evaluates to true", didn't know that.

Answer (score 2):

it is using the [bitwise OR operator](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html).  For starters, `1 | 1 = 1` so the second 1 is redundant.  If we remove the redundant 1 we are left with the equation `1 | 2 = 3`.  Looking at it in 2 bit binary it looks like:

`01 | 10 = 11`

The or operator will match up the corresponding bits from each or the values and if there is one 1 in either or both values for a given position, the result is a 1.  If both values for both the corresponding bits then the result is 0.